# Image output is just black in cv2 python

Tags: python, opencv

This is my code, all i want to do is filter the each color and see the image but the output is just black image all of them. my image for testing is [this](https://postimg.org/image/nlu75l8yh/) Please help me thanks.
I tried googling it but not results. Please help me .. Thanks :)

This is my code

```
def detect_colors(image):
    color_red = np.array([255,0,0])
    color_green = np.array([0, 255, 0])
    color_blue = np.array([0, 0, 255])
    def_color = np.array([0,0,0])
    red_mask = cv2.inRange(image,color_red,def_color)
    green_mask = cv2.inRange(image,color_green,def_color)
    blue_mask = cv2.inRange(image,color_blue,def_color)

    red_output = cv2.bitwise_and(image,image,mask=cv2.inRange(image,color_red,def_color))
    green_output = cv2.bitwise_and(image,image,mask=cv2.inRange(image,color_green,def_color))
    blue_output = cv2.bitwise_and(image,image,mask=cv2.inRange(image,color_blue,def_color))

    cv2.imshow('red',red_output)
    cv2.imshow('green',green_output)
    cv2.imshow('blue',blue_output)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: the boundaries you pass to the inRange method are in hsv format, not rgb

Comment: Oh so can you show me how to pass values in RGB ?

Comment: how do you load that image? by default opencv loads it as BRG. then your definitions of color_red and so on would be wrong. further you switched lower and upperbound in the inRange call. and all in all your code looks a bit complicated. show me how you load the image and I'll tell you how to fix it

Comment: Yeah that was the issue i accidentally passed the arguments incorrectly in inRange function. I found the solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of arguments i passed, was wrong.Thanks to "pigtel" i found it out.